# Two Levels Horizontal Accordion Menu

Tags: html

Please ,i need the same thing but with html5 not flash

http://www.oxylusflash.com/files/1571/index.html

do you know something ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't think its possible to do that with only `html5`

so if you really want them and can use jquery  then have a look at these

1) http://www.htmldrive.net/item/view/id/521

2) http://discovery.pulseextensions.com/2012/05/30-jquery-accordion-menu-best-example-an-tutorials/